# On duplicate key update all new data PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I have a 2 part html / php form, and one of the $_POST values is the session_id(); m which will be the unique ID in the database table.

On the first part of the form, the user eneters their contact information and it is inserted into a MySQL database.

```
INSERT INTO $table ($columns) VALUES ($values)
```

On the 2nd part of the form where they enter extra information, if the session_id() is the same, I just want to update all the columns that are being submitted, which will always be different from the columns in the first part of the form. How do I just update all columns being submitted while leaving previously submitted data intact.

In this example, $columns and $values are CSV string, i.e.

Submission 1

```
$columns = "'SSID', 'Name', 'Email'";
$values = "'65464s4468fff9864wef68d', 'John Doe', 'someone@something.com'";
```

Submission 2

```
$columns = "'SSID', 'Product', 'Comments'";
$Values = "'65464s4468fff9864wef68d', 'Apple', 'some comments'";
```

So I would just need to update the columns 'Product' and 'Comments'. I need to do this dynamically with many different forms so I would rather not have to specify which columns to update since they are already the only ones being inserted.

I'm attempting something like:

```
INSERT INTO $table ($columns) VALUES ($values) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE $columns = $columns
```

What would be the proper syntax? Currently this gives me a syntax error

Edit: Added last line

Comment: And your problem is? Any error message? Any behavior you didn't expect?

Comment: Nothing being inserted

Comment: Do you know why? Have you checked the query ran successfully but just happend to not insert stuff?

Comment: don't you think on duplicate key update?

Comment: @Dexa: I am expecting to hear from @chuckieDub about the result of executing `mysqli_error()` or any other function like this.

Comment: `$string = "INSERT INTO $table ($columns) VALUES ($values) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE $columns = $columns";
 
  if ($query = $mysqli->query($string)){
   
   return TRUE;
   echo "success...";
  }
  else
  {
   return FALSE; 
   echo $mysqli->error();
  }`

Comment: the above is returning no error that I can see

Comment: That is because you are returning before outputting errors

Comment: Thanks, now it says syntax error at line 1.

Comment: Then you introduced a syntax error with your change. Fix it.

Comment: Your error is at line $columns = $columns this doesn't mean anything. I assume you wanted $columns = $values, but even that will throw error with how it's written now. you need $column1 = $value1, $column2 = $value2 ...

Comment: And when you fixed it, you have to update your question with all the new info that you added in the comments: Say what the problem is (nothing inserted), tell us the code you are using to insert, and the exact error message from mysql.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do:

```
REPLACE INTO $table ($columns) VALUES ($values);
```

Comment: Actually scratch that. This wouldn't work in your case since you are only updating some fields at a time. Replace into deletes the duplicates record if it exists and then performs an insert, so any existing fields not being updated would be lost.